# How can I get the utc offset in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime, timezone

I need the utc offset from the timezone specified.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

```
require 'time'

p Time.zone_offset('EST') #=> -18000  #(-5*60*60)
```

Comment: Time.zone.utc_offset saved my day =)

Comment: Don't forget that in order for this to work properly, you have to set `config.time_zone = 'Berlin'` and `config.active_record.default_timezone = 'Berlin'` in application.rb (in my case, without that it didn't reflect daylight savings adjustments correctly)

Comment: @Charles, I had to change `config.active_record.default_timezone` to  `:local` instead of `'Santiago'`, otherwise every DateTime field change to nil. Is `Time.zone_offset` going to deal with daylight savings correctly?

Comment: Lucas' comment to the answer is the best... what steenslag proposes gets borked by daylight savings time if you rely on that offset changing when that happens. (EST vs EDT in this instance).

Comment: `Time.now.utc_offset` also works with DST while `Time.zone.utc_offset` does not.

Comment: Doesn't offset generally depend on a date?

Answer (score 44):

If you need to take daylight savings time into account, you can use something like this:

```
Time.now.in_time_zone('America/New_York').utc_offset
```

Comment: Thank you. This got me the correct offset where `Time.zone.utc_offset` did not.

Comment: @GregDubicki It's in Rails's `ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone`

Comment: This answer works better than `Time.zone.utc_offset`, which inexplicably doesn't account for Daylight Saving Time.

Answer (score 19):

```
Time.now.in_time_zone('Europe/London').formatted_offset
# => "+01:00"
```

For a string arguably more usable...

Answer (score 11):

```
my_date_time = DateTime.new(2011, 3, 29, 20)
#=> Tue, 29 Mar 2011 20:00:00 +0000

#will return the same time but with another offset
my_date_time.change(:offset => "+0100")
#=> Tue, 29 Mar 2011 20:00:00 +0100

#will return time for other offset
my_date_time.in_time_zone(-1)
#=>  Tue, 29 Mar 2011 19:00:00 -0100
```

Comment: this was what I wanted in the first place, a -N offset!

Answer (score 6):

If you are storing a user's timezone as a `Time.zone.name` string such as `'Eastern Time (US & Canada)'` as outlined in http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/TimeZone.html and want to get the timezone offset you can do this:

```
ActiveSupport::TimeZone.new(user.time_zone).utc_offset / 3600
# => -5
```

Comment: Keep in mind, this solution only returns the canonical offset and doesn't contemplate daylight saving time. So, to be safe, is better to use `Time.now.in_time_zone(user.time_zone).utc_offset / 3600`

Answer (score 5):

If you have a `ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone` object, you can call `time_zone.utc_offset` on it. So, for example, `Time.zone.now.time_zone.utc_offset`.

EDIT: You can also use the `gmt_offset` instance method on normal `Time` objects.

Answer (score 5):

I use `Time.zone.utc_offset / 1.hour` to get the offset in hours (e.g.: `-8` for San Francisco)

Answer (score 1):

Just to complete the loop here, right now I use:

`@course.start.utc_offset/60/60` in order to get the # of hours needed.  Jquery countdown needs just -5 or +3 in their `timezone` argument.

Your welcome google.